# FragmentTransaction within Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, android-imagebutton

im a new guy on this programming world so i guess this question is simple. So I have one imagebutton on my fragment and I whatI want is that when I click on it, it does a fragment transaction to another fragment; but the thing is that when I run the app and click on the imagebutton, it only "superimposes" the content of the other fragment into the one where the imagebutton is, of course what i want to do is just to go to the other fragment, ive been dealing with this for a while so I hope someone helps me, thanks.

Here is my java code of the fragment

```
public class inicio extends Fragment {

    public inicio() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio,container,false);

        ImageButton luces = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        luces.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                interior interior= new interior();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.inicioo, interior).commit();    

            }
        });
   }
}
```

New code added...

```
public class transaction extends MainActivity
        implements com.example.administradora.prueba.inicio.OnSelectedListener{


    public void onButtonSelected() {
        interior interior= new interior();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.inicioo, interior).commit();
    }
}
```

but i get this error in the logcat:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.administradora.prueba/com.example.administradora.prueba.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.administradora.prueba.MainActivity@20f8fe9b must implement OnSelectedListener

Comment: What is the name of your other Fragment? The reason why it "superimposes" is because you use `.replace` and specified the same id (`R.id.inicioo`).

Comment: My other fragment is called "interior", so could You please tell me how would the code be so that instead of "superimposing" it just gets me to the other fragment?

Comment: Please add the Layout XML file where you have declared your Fragments (this is usually your Activity layout file) - I need to see that so I can advise how your code needs to change.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't replace a Fragment from another Fragment. Try to do that through the Activity.

Define some interface for the Fragment to hold

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    OnSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnSelectedListener {
        public void onButtonSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnSelectedListener ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio,container,false);

        ImageButton luces = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        luces.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Send the event to the host activity
                if (mCallback != null) mCallback.onButtonSelected();
            }
        });

        return view;
   }
}
```

And swap the Fragment container in the interface implementation from the Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements MyFragment.OnSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onButtonSelected() {
        interior interior= new interior();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.inicioo, interior)
            .commit();    
    }
}
```

The first two sections of [**Communicating with Other Fragments**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I added the code you told me, but I run the app and it crashes and gives me the error i put above in my question, any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Your class doesn't implement the interface, just like the thrown exception says it should

Comment: You don't need to extend the Activity, you need to use the same Activity that first loaded the Fragment